# How to flash a router from FreeWRT to OpenWrt?

Tags: openwrt, router, firmware

How can I change the firmware on a router from FreeWRT to OpenWrt?

The router is a Linksys WRT54GL, so it should have enough memory for OpenWrt and I have SSH connection as root to the system.

Comment: this page is outdated, but gives some hints http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.uninstall may be mtd is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think the most direct route would be to flash your firmware back to the original manufacturer's first. Once you've reverted to the original firmware, you should only need to follow the directions to install the [OpenWrt firmware](https://openwrt.org/).

#### References

- [FreeWRT ADK](https://www.mirbsd.org/FreeWRT.htm)

Comment: Could you please give a hint, how to revert to the original firmware?

Comment: It depends on the device, but typically there's a reset button on the hardware. If you hold it in for a fairly long duration (maybe 20 secs) it will revert the firmware to the original manufaturer's.

Comment: Check out this section of Linksys' website: http://support.linksys.com/en-us/support/routers/WRT54G

Comment: The reset button can only reset the nvram, but will not write another system in the flash memory.

Comment: @JonasStein - then you'll have to follow the directions either described in the user manual or use one of the other methods described when you search for "Linksys WRT54GL original firmware" via google.

Comment: Here's one method, there are literally dozens: http://wrt54gl.wordpress.com/wrt54gl-debrick/. It highly depends on your current situation. With FreeWRT, that's a dead project from what I can tell, so you'll likely not find much on how to get off of it, since the main site is gone. The ADK site contained a snapshot of the site, but it looked like a bit of a pain to navigate through it.

Comment: Other methods are described here wrt getting the old firmware back: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Recover_from_a_Bad_Flash. Look in the WRTG54G section, they explain how to hold the button in and get into "management mode".